# Regular expression in PHP

Tags: php, regex

```
str = "abc xyz asdf @ Rs1.5/day.poi qwerty."
```

I want to use regex in PHP and convert it into `"abc xyz asdf @ Re1/day.poi qwerty."`

ie, i want to replace the substring `"Rs1.5/day"`(say s1) with `"Re.1/day"`(say s2)

Here s1 and s2 can be any string in the format `(Rs|Re)<digit>[.<digit>]/[<number>day(s)]`

How the expression should be?

Comment: You want the decimal portion of the number removed? Your question is not clear.

Comment: Depending on the meaning of the string (which looks quite curious to me) parsing (for example using `explode()` or such) would make more sense

Comment: thanks for all! I was hunting the expression `/(Rs|Re)?\s*\.?\s*\d*\s*\.?\s*\d+\s*(Rs|Re)?\s*\.?\s*\/?\s*\d*\s*(every)?days?/i`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for this:

```
$str = "abc xyz asdf @ Rs1.5/day.poi qwerty.";
$rep = "(Rs|Re)?\s*\.?\s*\d*\.?\d+\/\d*days?"
$str = preg_replace($rep, "Re$1", $str)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's your answer.

```
<?
 $str = "abc xyz asdf @ Rs1.5/day.poi qwerty.";
 print_r($str);
 echo "<br />";
 $newStr = preg_replace("/(\.[0-9]+)/", "", $str);
 print_r($newStr);
?>
```

Removes the decimals from numbers or strings with numbers as decimals.

Comment: it should be Re if the digit is 1, else Rs

Comment: This doesn't work. `${1}` produces a notice (Undifined variable). I think you want to use `$1` instead, but, unfortunately, it doesn't do anything ie: replace group 1 by group 1 !!

Comment: Hm, strange.. Must've forgotten to remove that (Had two groups from the start to ensure there was only numbers in front of the decimal). And I didn't get a notice from it, maybe my php is broken. :) I'll edit to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
$str = "abc xyz asdf @ Rs1.5/day.poi qwerty.";
$str = preg_replace("/Rs(\d+)(?:\.\d*)/", "Re$1", $str);
```

Comment: some times my str become `"abc xyz asdf @ Re1/day.poi qwerty."` and I may need to replace "Re1/day" with "Rs5/5days"

Comment: @Sayuj: I don't see what you want exactly. Coud you provide in your question some examples of input strings and what you want on output.